# DTO gets lost in transmission POST to REST API?

Tags: angular9, asp.net-core-3.1, ionic5

My object is being lost in transmission. I (1) enter some text, (2) submit a form and (3) see the correct `POST` and (3) I see the objects construction is correct and (3) that the `http.post` method is being used. However on the ServerSide I see (4) that the controller is receiving a `null` object.  Please help!

[image]

[image]

Using Angular 9, Ionic 5's `http` client... very straightforward... .NET Core 3.1 c# backend...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I needed to add the `[ApiController]` attribute to the controller.